# How can i add any other APIs in SDK manager?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

i have installed the latest version of sdk-manager but when i open it, the sdk-manager has no android platform version(APIs), but Android 4.4!

In other words when i create a new "Android Application Project" in eclipse i only have 1 choice for item "Compile With:", that is API19:Android4.4(KitKat)!!!!

What's problem? How can i add any other APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here:

[Adding Platforms and Packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)

It is a rather straightforward procedure. In general http://developer.android.com/ is the place to look for any similar questions!

Comment: thanks a lot, but i visited it before.my problem is that there is no any APIs in my SDK manager that i want to install them!! which i couldn't found any guidance about it!

Comment: unfortunately i have no reputations to upload the screenshots!:(

Comment: Go to Help -> Install new software.
Click on Add button.
Add the link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse.
Expand Developer tools. Inside that select Android DDMS and Android Developer Tools. Uncheck Show only latest versions.
Click finish. Restart eclipse. Go to Help -> Check for updates. Complete all the updates. Then go to Window -> Android SDK Manager.
You'll find all available versions. Does this work?